# How to convert 2d array to set in python

Tags: python, arrays, set

I have a following 2D array

`y=[[0, 3], [3, 0], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2]]`

I would like to convert it like this

`S = [set(y[0]),  set(y[1]),  set(y[2]),  set(y[3])]`

So after doing operation S is like this

`S = [set([0,3]), set([3,0]), set([1, 2, 3]), set([1, 2])]`

I tried the following code but no luck

`for i in range(len(y)):`

`S = [set(y[i])]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use list comprehension:

```
S = [set(x) for x in y]
```

Comment: If it helped you, make sure to accept the answer with the green v button :)